# angular2 rc.4 ng-content duplicated dont work

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement an "editComponent" that can be shown in a pageComponent or in a dialogComponent, but uplicated **ng-content** tag in the same component don't work (only works the las **ng-content** tag):

```
<div *ngIf="dialog">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

<!-- for pages not in dialog popups put all div structure -->
<div *ngIf="!dialog" class="container content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

All children are transcluded to the `<ng-content>` with the matching selector.
All non-matching children are transcluded to the first `<ng-content>` that doesn't have a `select="..."` attribute.

If the children are passed as `<template>` there are more possibilities.

There are plans to support more flexible (dynamic) transclusion scenarios, but currently this is rather static.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally implemented this way:

```
<!-- for pages in dialog popups remove classes and header -->
<div [ngClass]="{'container content':!dialog}">
  <div class="page-header" *ngIf="!dialog">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  </div>
  <div [ngClass]="{'row':!dialog}">
    <div [ngClass]="{'col-md-12':!dialog}">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only one ng-content tag removing all div classes and header.

Comment: Alternativelly trying to get this working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783793/angular2rc-4-viewresolver-get-component-instance